# Titanic Dataset throwing error at predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been doing the Kaggle 30 days of ML course and we're at the two week mark. I just finished the two ML courses on Kaggle and wanted to revisit the titanic dataset and see if I could do a better job with it. I'm having trouble tho. I do a bit of pre-processing at the start to remove 12 nan values at the top of the train and test set. Then I make a pipeline using SimpleImputer and OridinalEncoder. The pipeline seems to fit X_train and y_train without issue. Then, I try to run the impute and encode on the test set, I get a new df with clean values, but the pipeline doesn't predict on it and throws this error:

ValueError: Found unknown categories [0.0, 1.0] in column 0 during transform

Can anyone advise?

I'll put what I think are relevant pieces of code below:

```
numerical_cols = [col for col in X_train.columns if X_train[col].dtypes in ['int64', 'float64']]
categorical_cols = [col for col in X_train.columns if X_train[col].dtypes == 'object']
```

--

```
#Pipeline

numerical_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
    ('encoder', OrdinalEncoder())
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [
    ('num', numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
    ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
])

model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators = 500)

pipe = Pipeline(steps = [
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', model)
])
```

--

```
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

--

```
# Processing Test Data
X_test = X_test.dropna(axis = 0)

# Imputing
impute_X_test = pd.DataFrame(numerical_transformer.fit_transform(X_test[numerical_cols]))

impute_X_test.columns = X_test[numerical_cols].columns


# Encoding
label_X_test = categorical_transformer.fit_transform(X_test[categorical_cols])
```

--

```
X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(label_X_test, columns = ['Sex','Cabin'])
final_X_test = pd.concat([impute_X_test, X_test_df], axis = 1)
final_X_test
```

--

```
pipe.predict(final_X_test)
```

Error is thrown here at the end.

Comment: I think your issue is that you are processing the test data twice. Why are you using `numerical_transformer` separately when it is already part of the pipeline. Try removing it and testing it.

Comment: @AyushGoel when I run pipe.predict(X_test) after fitting the pipe I get thrown this error: 'ValueError: Found unknown categories ['C130', 'C105', 'B26', 'A11', 'E52', 'C85', 'C132', 'C51', 'B11', 'E46', 'C55 C57', 'E45', 'C6', 'D40', 'D34', 'B10', 'F E57', 'B61', 'D22', 'A18', 'C80', 'B24', 'C97', 'C116', 'F E46', 'A9', 'C53', 'C31', 'C89', 'B45', 'E39 E41', 'D43', 'C39', 'D38', 'A29', 'B36', 'E60', 'A21', 'C28', 'B52 B54 B56', 'F'] in column 1 during transform' Those values are related to the 'Cabin' column in the dataset

Comment: I see. The issue arises when the test data has some unseen values in the categorical variable. To fix this, first concatenate the train and test data. Then run `pd.dummies` on any categorical variables you want. Then split the data back into train and test, and your current code should work.

Comment: "*I'll put what I think are relevant pieces of code below*" - please don't do that, post a [mre] nstead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happen when your test dataset do not match with dataset you used in training. let suppose you train your model on data that contains 5 Columns, and on prediction you give it 4 columns or 6, or 3 etc. then it gives the error. On the other hand one more case is that let suppose you give it 5 columns but if columns type that used in training are not same in prediction then this also result in error.